# Add external users in SharePoint 2013

Tags: access-rights

I would like to allow some externals users to connect on my SharePoint site that is connected to an LDAP.
-SharePoint 2013 enterprise edition-
Can you help me once again...?

Comment: Is your web application claims enabled ?

Comment: Thanks, but there is no easier way to manage this?...

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options. Simplest would be to use an FBA pack like this one.
http://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/
This would allow you to have user accounts for non-ldap users.
The other option would be to use Azure ACS to plug in Facebook and other identity providers into your SP environment.
http://dannyjessee.com/blog/index.php/2012/11/using-azure-acs-to-sign-in-to-sharepoint-2013-with-facebook/
This is somewhat more complex, but means less management of user accounts, password resets, etc for you to manage.